# Convert GLfloat [] array to GLfloat * array

Tags: objective-c, c, opengl-es, objective-c++

Is there a quicker way to convert the following data into a c style pointer array?

```
GLfloat verticalLines [] = {
0.59, 0.66, 0.0,    
0.59, -0.14, 0.0
}
```

My current approach is to manually iterate over the data using the method below:

```
-(GLfloat *)updateLineVertices{

int totalVertices = 6;
GLfloat *lineVertices =  (GLfloat *)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * (totalVertices));

for (int i = 0; i<totalVertices; i++) {
    lineVertices[i] = verticalLines[i];
}

return lineVertices;
}
```

Some additional info.
Ultimately I will need the data in a format which can be easily manipulated, for example:

```
-(void)scaleLineAnimation{
GLfloat *lineVertices = [self updateLineVertices];
for (int i = 0; i<totalVertices; i+=3) {
     lineVertices[i+1] += 0.5; //scale y axis
}
}
```

Comment: per needing to deal with the array as a coordinates, it might help that you can "magically" turn an array into a matrix, by using the right element addressing scheme, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281728/is-there-a-way-to-make-objective-c-support-a-multi-variable-switch-construct/6366364#6366364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if verticalLines is going to stick around or not. If it's defined like it is above and it's not going to change, you can forgo the whole malloc and just point lineVertices to it.

```
linesVertices = &verticalLines[0]
```

if verticalLines is going to change, you probably want your own copy, so you've got no choice but to copy the actual data from one part of memory to another as you are doing, that being said, this might be a bit more elegant

```
for (int i = 0; i<totalVertices; i++){
    lineVertices[i] = verticalLines[i];
}
```

or the preferred method is probably to use memcopy(), here is some working code

```
//MemcopyTest.c
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   float a[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0};     //Original Array

   int size = sizeof(float)*3;      
   float *b = (float*)malloc(size); //Allocate New Array
   memcpy(b, a, size);              //Copy Data

   for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
      printf("%f\n", b[i]);
   }
   free(b);
}
```

Comment: Yes the data is going to change. I was hoping there would be a magical cast type operation...something like GLfloat *lineVertices =  (GLfloat *) verticalLines; Having said that i can use the elegant solution to start with and use the original format in other parts of my program where i need to manipulate the data - the format simply helps me identify the x,y,z elements.

Comment: Well, if you want to involve string.h, I guess you could user memcpy ;/ (see update above).

Comment: thanks i'm already using memcpy to construct vbo's but i'm sure it wouldn't hurt performance to use it here also

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just using `verticalLines` directly? Anything of type `T ident[n]` can be implicitly converted to `T* ident` as if you had written `&ident[0]`. And if you really want to be explicit, you can just write `&ident[0]` directly.